# Get value from Read command and assign to a variable

Tags: bash, command-line, sh

I have a simple script that is something like the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
NUM=$(read -p "Number: ")
echo $NUM
```

When I run this from the command line i don't seem to get any value
How can one take the results of read command that needs to be run within a script, save it to a variable, and then output that variable on the screen?

Comment: You need to read the documentation of the `read` command. You give it variable names as arguments and it assigns them directly, it doesn't output anything.

Comment: `read -p "Number: " NUM`

Comment: Stop guessing syntax usage and read the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all else fails, try the documentation. From `read --help`:

> Reads a single line from the standard input, or from file descriptor FD
> if the -u option is supplied.  The line is split into fields as with word
> splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
> word to the second NAME, and so on, with any leftover words assigned to
> the last NAME.  Only the characters found in $IFS are recognized as word
> delimiters.
> If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the REPLY variable.

So:

```
read -p "Number: " NUM
echo $NUM
```

should do what you want. Alternatively

```
read -p "Number: "
echo $REPLY
```

would do the same thing, with little less typing.